# Is there a x64 OAuth DLL for PHP 5.4?

Tags: php, windows, oauth, pecl

I'm looking for a the PECL OAuth DLL for 64 bit Windows and PHP 5.4.  Does anyone know where I can find the DLL (assuming it exists somewhere out there)?

There are similar questions on Stack Overflow, however I've gone through all the questions I could find and most of the solutions point at a few websites to download the DLL.  Unfortunately none of these websites have the DLL I'm looking for.

- http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ -only **PHP 5.3** and **x86**
- http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/oauth/1.2.2/ -
  has *PHP 5.4* but only **x86**
- http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/oauth/1.2.3/ -
  has *PHP 5.4* but only **x86**
- http://www.mediafire.com/php-win64-extensions - has *x64* but only
  **PHP 5.3**

Comment: @AdamD, thanks for making the question title more clear.

Comment: @Gilles, thanks for removing the last line to reflect that the links were added.

Answer (score 1):

Here,

```
php_oauth-1.2.3-5.4-VC9-x64.zip
```

http://www.mediafire.com/download/kdnxvxva6e0k5an/php_oauth-1.2.3-5.4-VC9-x64.zip

All other x64 php extensions

http://www.mediafire.com/php-win64-extensions

Answer (score 0):

I have searched for this recently but no luck. So short answer.

#### NO